# Trying to add special character (%) sign to variable with following concatenation sign in ESQL, it gives me the the below error

Tags: messagebroker, extended-sql

Trying to add special character (%) sign to variable with following concatenation sign, but it gives me the the error: Invalid characters.

```
DECLARE Percent CHARACTER CAST ( ' %' AS CHARACTER CCSID 1208);

SET AlocatedAmount = 45

SET InPercent = AlocatedAmount||'%'
```

**Result should be**: InPercent = 45%

**Error**:Invalid characters::45 %

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Is part of the trouble that you declared `Percent` but are trying to modify `InPercent`?

Comment: You should include a complete source excerpt in your question, so we can see exactly what type your variables are.

Comment: So you are trying to concatenate an INTEGER(AllocatedAmount) with CHAR('%') the ESQL concatenation operator only works with Strings aka CHAR. I've also put an answer below showing how to use CAST and FORMAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is also the option of using FORMAT in your CAST

```
DECLARE Num INTEGER;
DECLARE FormattedStr CHAR;  
SET Num = 45;
SET FormattedStr = CAST(Num AS CHAR FORMAT '#0%');
```

More information can be found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05615_.htm

Answer (score 1):

AlocatedAmount seems to be an INTEGER, on what you cannot use the concatenation operator.
You need to cast that to CHARACTER first:

```
SET InPercent = CAST(AlocatedAmount AS CHARACTER) || '%';
```